# Add view to windowmanager in Service

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I want to add `View` to `WindowManager` in `Service`. But it has to be like a normal activity: if user will press home or back button this `Service` will have to close itself. Can you please tell me which type of windowmanager should I use?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want behavior like an activity, use an activity.

Comment: @commonsware Well, why I don't use an activity? Because activity is big covers whole screen but I need something way smaller. That's why I want to use WindowManager

Comment: Why not use an activity with a different theme, like one of the `Dialog` themes (e.g., `Theme.Material.Dialog`)? For example, pretty much all of the popup "dialogs" that you see from the system are actually activities using a theme that constrains the activity window size.

Comment: @commonsware Thank you. But I also need that I will be able to run 2 different application. Shall I be able to do this?(if one application's activity is using dialog theme and another application's activity is using a normal theme)

Comment: Your activity can float over another activity, as do the system dialogs. However, if you are in the foreground, all input goes to you; the user cannot interact with the underlying activity. This is much the same if you go with your separate-window approach: AFAIK, only the foreground activity gets key input, not your window.

Comment: @commonsware You are talking about system dialog,right? And for example, I want to run custom calculator and my app with system dialog both of them will be shown on display,right?

Comment: Yes, both will be shown. Which of those the user can *interact* with will vary by implementation. Your question indicates that you want to receive key input. You cannot respond to the HOME button unless you are a home screen. And if you can receive the BACK button and other key input, then whatever else is on the screen *cannot* receive the BACK button and other key input. AFAIK, to achieve everything that you appear to want, you will have to create a custom version of Android, roll that into a custom ROM, and install that on your device.

Comment: @commonsware I don't want to block home or back button pressing but I want to detect them using system dialog(BTW, is it a type of window?) that will be before another app.